# Редакция SQL- запроса( JOIN, WHERE, GROUP BY,)

Tags: sql

Определить, какие товары имеются в таблице Goods, но не покупались в течение 2005 года

Поля в результирующей таблице: good_name

[**ВОТ ССЫЛКА НА ЗАДАНИЕ**](https://sql-academy.org/ru/trainer/tasks/25)

Этот код выдает правильный результат запроса,НО!!!! Я НЕ ЗАТРАГИВАЮ 2005 ГОД,КУДА МНЕ НАДО ЭТО `YEAR(Payments.date) = 2005` ДОБАВИТЬ?
Пыталась добавить `WHERE Payments.good IS NULL AND  YEAR(Payments.date) = 2005` - ВЫДАЕТ ОШИБКУ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение

```
SELECT good_name FROM Goods                                                        
LEFT JOIN Payments ON 
 Goods.good_id = Payments.good
 AND YEAR(Payments.date) = 2005
WHERE  Payments.good IS NULL
GROUP BY 
 good_id;
```

да конечно пока на данные не посмотришь не определишь вот так вот сходу

Answer (score 0):

Другое решение

```
SELECT good_name FROM Goods
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT good FROM Payments 
WHERE good = good_id AND YEAR(date) = '2005')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]